# Getting the message NDSolve::ndnum

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to ask why the machine always has the error "Integrand has evaluated non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.,1.0401}}" when I calculate TRS[1.1] ? The code is as follows.

```
tpa = 6;
a1 = (tpa + 1.08) Pi/(tpa + 0.1);
b1 = (tpa + 1.8) Pi/(tpa + 1.3);
a2 = tpa Pi/(tpa + 1.19);
b2 = (tpa + 1.37) Pi/(tpa + 2);
m1 = 0.45;
m2 = 0.55;
lambda1 = 2.6*(10^(-4));
lambda2 = lambda1*(m1/m2)^2;
Mpl = 1;
k = -1;

(*Define the saxion. *)
chi10 =  (b2 Log[lambda1] - b1 Log[lambda2])/(a2 b1 - a1 b2) ;
chi20 = - (a2 Log[lambda1] - a1 Log[lambda2])/(a2 b1 - a1 b2) ;


(*Define the decay constants. *)
f1 = 1/a1 ;
f2 = 1/b1 ;
g1 = 1/a2 ;
g2 = 1/b2 ;

(*Define the Amplitudes. *)
Lambda1 = ((m1^4 lambda1^2)/(2 k chi10 chi20))^(1/4) ;
Lambda2 = ((m2^4 lambda2^2)/(2 k chi10 chi20))^(1/4) ;


(*Effective decay constants after KNP mechanism *)
fpsi = (f1 f2)/(Sqrt[(f1)^2 + (f2)^2]) ;
fpsiprime = (g1 g2 (Sqrt[(f1)^2 + (f2)^2]))/(f1 g1 + f2 g2) ;
feff = (g1 g2 (Sqrt[(f1)^2 + (f2)^2]))/(Abs[f1 g2 - f2 g1]) ;

(*Define the parameters for the calculations.*)
(*Potential Derivatives*)
V[phi1_, phi2_] := (Lambda1)^(4) ( 1 - Cos[ phi1/ fpsi] ) +(Lambda2)^(4) ( 1 - Cos[ phi1/fpsiprime + phi2/feff ] ) ;

(*1st Derivatives*)
V1[phi1_, phi2_] = D[V[phi1, phi2], {phi1, 1}];
V2[phi1_, phi2_] = D[V[phi1, phi2], {phi2, 1}];
(*2nd Derivatives*)
V11[phi1_, phi2_] = D[V[phi1, phi2], {phi1, 2}];
V12[phi1_, phi2_] = D[V[phi1, phi2], phi1, phi2];
V22[phi1_, phi2_] = D[V[phi1, phi2], {phi2, 2}];

(*Define the rotation angle.*)
Theta[phi1_, phi2_] := ArcTan[V1[phi1, phi2], V2[phi1, phi2]];

(*Define the rotations of the 1st derivatives of potential.*)
VSigma[phi1_, phi2_] := V1[phi1, phi2]*Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]] + V2[phi1, phi2]*Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]];

(*Define the slow-roll parameters.*)
(*1st order slow-roll parameters.*)
 Epsilon11[phi1_, phi2_] := (1/2) (Mpl)^2 (V1[phi1, phi2]/V[phi1, phi2])^2 ; 
Epsilon12[phi1_, phi2_] := (1/2) (Mpl)^2 (V1[phi1, phi2]/V[phi1, phi2]) 
(V2[phi1, phi2]/V[phi1, phi2]) ;
Epsilon22[phi1_, phi2_] := (1/2) (Mpl)^2 (V2[phi1, phi2]/V[phi1, phi2])^2 ;

(*2nd order slow-roll parameters.*)
Eta11[phi1_, phi2_] := (Mpl)^2 V11[phi1, phi2]/V[phi1, phi2] ;
Eta12[phi1_, phi2_] := (Mpl)^2 V12[phi1, phi2]/V[phi1, phi2] ;
Eta22[phi1_, phi2_] := (Mpl)^2 V22[phi1, phi2]/V[phi1, phi2] ;

(*High order derivative terms of potential.*)
(*2nd order*)
VSigmaSigma [phi1_, phi2_] := (Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2) V11[phi1,phi2] + 2 (Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]) (Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]]) V12[phi1, phi2] +(Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2) V22[phi1, phi2] ;
VSigmaS[phi1_, phi2_] := - Sin[Theta[phi1,phi2]]Cos[Theta[phi1,phi2]]V11[phi1, phi2] +(Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 -Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2) V12[phi1, phi2] + Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]] V22[phi1, phi2] ;
VSS[phi1_, phi2_] := Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 V11[phi1, phi2] -2Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]] V12[phi1, phi2] + Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 V22[phi1, phi2] ;

(*Slow-roll parameters after the rotations to sigma and s.*)
(*1st order slow-roll parameters.*)
Epsilon[phi1_, phi2_] := Epsilon11[phi1, phi2] + Epsilon22[phi1, phi2];

(*2nd order slow-roll parameters.*)
EtaSigmaSigma[phi1_, phi2_] := Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 Eta11[phi1,phi2] + 2 Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Eta12[phi1, phi2] + Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 Eta22[phi1, phi2] ;
EtaSigmaS[phi1_, phi2_] := - Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Cos[Theta[phi1,phi2]] Eta11[phi1, phi2] + (Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 - Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2) Eta12[phi1, phi2] + Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Eta22[phi1, phi2] ;
EtaSS[phi1_, phi2_] := Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 Eta11[phi1, phi2] - 2Sin[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]] Eta12[phi1, phi2] + Cos[Theta[phi1, phi2]]^2 Eta22[phi1, phi2] ;

(*Numerical calculations of phi1 and phi2*)
ww = - 0.95;  (* As required, w < -1/3 *)
numsol = NDSolve[{phi1''[t] + 3(2/(3(1+ww)t))phi1'[t] +((Lambda1)^4/fpsi) Sin[(phi1[t]/fpsi)] == 0, phi2''[t] + 3(2/(3(1+ww)t))phi2'[t] + ((Lambda2)^4/fpsiprime) Sin[(phi1[t]/fpsiprime) +(phi2[t]/feff)] == 0, phi1[1] == 4.374641, phi2[1] == 15.2, phi1'[1] == 0, phi2'[1] == 0}, {phi1, phi2}, {t, 0.01, 100000}] ; (* phi'’+3 H phi’ + V’ == 0 *) 

Alpha[t_] := 2 EtaSigmaS[phi1[t], phi2[t]]/. numsol ;
BBeta[t_] := -2 Epsilon[phi1[t], phi2[t]] + EtaSigmaSigma[phi1[t], phi2[t]] - EtaSS[phi1[t], phi2[t]]/. numsol ;
TSS[t_ /; t > 0.999] = Exp[Integrate[BBeta[x] (2/(3 (1 + ww) x)), {x, 1, t},Assumptions -> {t > 0.999}]];
TRS[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Alpha[x] (2/(3 (1 + ww) x)) TSS[x], {x, 1, t}];
ParametricPlot[{TSS[t], TRS[t]}, {t, 1, 1.1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Originally, I wanted to make the parametric plot between TSS[t] and TRS[t], but it was in vain. So I tried to fix it by considering the simple case like calculating TRS[1.1]. But, the computer told me that "Integrand has evaluated non-numerical values in the region". Does anyone know the reason why and how to solve. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Look at the differential equations in NDSolve. You will see, that you didn't define k.

Comment: Look at the definitions `Lambda1 = ((m1^4 lambda1^2)/(2 k chi10 chi20))^(1/4); Lambda2 = ((m2^4 lambda2^2)/(2 k chi10 chi20))^(1/4);` `k` is blue not black, so it is undefined. That is most likely the source of your error message.

Comment: Thank you for your remind. Even though I define 'k = -1', it also shows "Integrand has evaluated non-numerical values in the region".

Answer (score 1):

Several minor changes to the last five lines of code resolve the issues in the question.

```
Alpha[t_] := 2 EtaSigmaS[phi1[t], phi2[t]] /. First[numsol];
BBeta[t_] := -2 Epsilon[phi1[t], phi2[t]] + EtaSigmaSigma[phi1[t], phi2[t]] 
    - EtaSS[phi1[t], phi2[t]] /. First[numsol] ;
TSS[t_ /; t > 0.999] := NIntegrate[BBeta[x] (2/(3 (1 + ww) x)), {x, 1., t}]
TRS[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Alpha[x] (2/(3 (1 + ww) x)) TSS[x], {x, 1., t}]
Table[{TSS[t], TRS[t]}, {t, 1., 1.1, .01}]
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image]

The changes are these:

1. Replace `numsol` by `First[numsol]`, so that the output of `Alpha` and `Beta` are not one-element lists.
2. Replace `Set` by `SetDelayed` in `TSS` to prevent it from evaluating immediately.
3. Replace `Integrate` by `NIntegrate` in `TSS` to greatly improve speed.
4. Replace `1` by `1.` in the limits of integration in `TSS` and `TRS`.
5. Replace `ParametricPlot` by `Table` and `ListLinePlot` to greatly improve speed.